# Permission denied (publickey) using ProxyCommand

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have two servers which I ssh jump into using a third server. I can get into one of the servers, but not the other, even though my public key is marked on both servers under `authorized_keys`.

My local MacOS `~/.ssh/config` looks like this:

```
Host node* !node-hopper
ProxyCommand ssh node-hopper -W %h:9222 #nc -w 90 %h 9222
ForwardAgent yes
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%r@%h-%p
ControlPersist 600
ServerAliveInterval 30
User foobar
```

The only difference between the two servers (I can find) is that one is running Ubuntu 16.04.6 and the other is running Ubuntu 14.04.5.

Do you know why I cannot get into one of the servers? Or even what should I check? I'm totally out of ideas.

Comment: Both is out of support several years ago. Upgrade to a supported release

Comment: I agree that the servers need to be updated, but is that the reason? Shouldn't SSH still work fine? Especially since it's working on one server.

Comment: Run `ssh -vvv user@host` to include debugging info. This will show where it stops. [Edit] your question to add the info. But I would actually suspect 14.04 is old enough that things like `ssh`can start to break soon. It's nearly ten years old.

Comment: I will add it later. Good for 14.04 though! Guy has been running for 10 years!

Comment: I found other servers that had the same problem, all were on 14.04. After updating one of them it started working. I'm unsure of the precise issue, but for now this solution is good enough and I will not dig deeper. Thanks!

Comment: **Are you using an RSA key, and OpenSSH 8.8 up client** on the Mac? 8.8 up by default disables the old-and-weak ssh-rsa _algorithm_ (allowing only the newer rsa-sha2 ones, which use the same _key_) but Ubuntu 14.04 has/had OpenSSH 6.6 which implemented only ssh-rsa; you can **override the client with `ssh -oPubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa ...`**. There are _many_ Qs on this already. OTOH if you use an ECDSA or Ed25519 key it should work (even) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in Ubuntu 14.04. After updating to a newer release it started working.